# Overfitting on the training data while still improving on the validation data

Tags: r, xgboost, overfitting-underfitting

I am fitting a binary classification model with XGBoost in R. My dataset has 300k observations with 3 continious predictors and 1 one-hot-encoded factor variabele with 90 levels. The dependent variable `y` is True or False.

I have done random subsampling to find the optimal hyperparameters. For every setting I have done 5 fold (grouped) CV. The hyperparameter-settings below resulted in the highest average AUC on the 5 fold valuation data folds:

```
booster  objective        max_depth  eta        subsample  colsample_bytree   min_child_weight
gbtree   binary:logistic  8          0.7708479  0.2861735  0.5338721          1
```

Next I have used these hyperparamer-settings in the XGBoost-model fitting below:

```
model_n <- xgb.train(data = xgb_trainval,
                         booster = "gbtree",
                         objective = "binary:logistic",
                         max_depth = 8,
                         eta = 0.7708479,
                         subsample = 0.2861735,
                         colsample_bytree = 0.5338721,
                         min_child_weight = 1,
                         nrounds = 1000,
                         eval_metric = "auc",
                         early_stopping_rounds = 30,
                         print_every_n = 100,
                         watchlist = list(train = xgb_trainval, val = xgb_val)
    )
```

I have visualized the evaluation log in this way:

```
model_iterations <- model_n$evaluation_log$iter
model_train_auc <- model_n$evaluation_log$train_auc
model_val_auc <- model_n$evaluation_log$val_auc
```

[image]

I conclude that the model is overfitting on the training data since the AUC becomes close to 1 after 200 iterations. At the same time the model is still improving on the validation data. On one hand I would conclude that the model after 500 iterations can't be a good model since it is strongly overfitting on the training data. On the other hand this model has the highest AUC on the validation data.

Can this model be optimal if it is strongly overfitting on the train data as seen above or should I tune further to have a model which has less overfitting on the training data (with a similar or even slightly lower AUC on the validation data)?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, in response to your comment below, it is fine to overfit on the training data if the model is stable on new data. See Ying 2019, "we use validation set to figure out a perfect set of values for the hyper-parameters, and later use the test set to do the final evaluation of accuracy." And https://machinelearningmastery.com/overfitting-machine-learning-models/ . Also on Kaggle it has often been used to keep training at or near 100 pct fit with a much lower but improving fit on new data. But you must inspect the final residuals. Is your model fitting to capture the most important observations?

Comment: Thank you for these interesting articles. If I read the source from the first footnote of Ying's paper, it is mentioned that "For example, it would be a big red flag if our model saw 99% accuracy on the training set but only 55% accuracy on the test set.". See: https://elitedatascience.com/overfitting-in-machine-learning . Also intiutively I would expect that a model with 99% accuracy on the trainingset would have a lot of unnecessary complexity within it. Although indeed the mlmastery website mentions the opposite.

Comment: I agree with the feeling that it is not a legit approach. It is however observed by top kagglers that they can make a NNet generalize well to new data by training beyond 100 pct, ie reach 100 pct and keep training and then it will eventually generalize. This is a more formal look at it: https://youtu.be/dND-7llwrpw

Comment: The more I read about the subject, the more I realize that there are many views about overfitting. This post supports to reduce the gap between performances on train and test sets. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131233/neural-network-over-fitting/131234#131234 while this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515588/train-acc-vs-validation-acc defines overfitting as: meaning that the model had started to learn the random variability in the data, at the expense of an decrease in generalisation performance. I think indeed we can conclude that overfitting on traindata is not

Comment: bad per se, alhough at the same time it is a good thing to minimize the gap between performances on train and test sets.

Comment: Remarkable that in the Grokking paper they reach a 100% fit at validation data. I suppose this is only possible if there is no noise in the validation data?

Comment: Yes, I think that result is just because they use synthetic data.

Comment: Thanks for all your explanations. This gave me a better understanding. Final question: Would you be totally indifferent to overfitting on the trainingdata or would you prefer to minimize the gap between performances on train and test sets as in the posts above if possible?

Comment: minimize the gap. If not possible, use a package like LIME with partial dependency plots and more, or similar package, to see if the variable effects made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a viable strategy, but have a final unseen test set.

Also check on all the data, that you are happy with the observations, it scores well on vs the observations it does not.

Are you satisfied with the cases, the model cannot handle?

If not, train with weighting, so the important type of cases is handled well and the less important cases are perhaps not.

Comment: @ niels kristian schmidt Thank you. Sorry that my question is not precise enough. My main question is if a model can be optimal if it is strongly overfitting on the train data. Or should I tune further to have a model which has less overfitting on the training data. I will modify the question above.